# Лишние два байта при получении байтов из строки

Tags: java

Есть такой код:

```
String testEmail = "player@gmail.com";
byte[] email = testEmail.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16);
```

В результате имею:

```
-2   -1   0   112   0   108   0 ...
```

-2 и -1 какой-то мусор получается или что это вообще? Так как потом последние два байта отсутствуют...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это маркер последовательности байтов (`byte order mark` - `BOM`), вставляется для обозначения кодировки Юникод. По сути UTF-16 это 2 байта информации и этот маркер обозначается как `0xFEFF`, но так как вы выводите по байту получается -2 и -1.

Чтобы избавиться от них, можете использовать `StandardCharsets.UTF_16BE`.